# Vue js v-for not working when array passed from laravel backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I don't get it for some reason when i pass array through props v-for wont work and only difference i can see from directly writing data is that one passed from props don't have spaces in between.

I am using laravel and through blade im passing data to vue, data is array of all photos with informations. But that data won't list through all photos and display div's.

Let me show you my code:

This is what i have in blade template:

```
<picture-upload
    :input_value="'{{ json_encode($profilephotos) }}'"
    :bind_user="'{{ $profile->id }}'"
    :input_name="'profilephoto'"
    :post_url="'{{ route('photouploads') }}'"
    :type="'profilephoto'"
></picture-upload>
```

I don't think that `json_encode` make difference in this case but i tried it any way.

And this is what i have in my `photos.vue` file

```
props: ['input_name', 'post_url', 'bind_user', 'type', 'input_value'],
    data() {
        return {
            files: [],
            uploads: this.input_value,
            items: [
              {"id":110,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"5.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"3f49191095d302fb7e66ce037dd5efa111287e8230964ad8a3170687ca4336a1","size":192445,"created_at":"2019-04-23 16:04:01","updated_at":"2019-04-23 16:04:01"},
              {"id":111,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52","updated_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52"},
              {"id":112,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"5.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b","size":192445,"created_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52","updated_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52"},
              {"id":113,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"ffe6f95d10c5249390fcea140fe15a1fb57f5d29626a947e4a999db50f3ea295","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:00:10","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:00:10"},
              {"id":114,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"75a00a901f1a01a0267d44bebc8574efa9eb7a7edfd395e29dabb289efb353ac","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:05:32","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:05:32"}
            ]
        }
    },
```

So `input_value` is what is passed from blade template, and `items` is what i added manually for testing, `items` is exactly the same as what i see when i output data in frontend.

Here is what i have in .`vue <template>` section

```
{{ items }}

<li v-for="item in items">
   {{ item.type }}
</li>

{{ uploads }}

<div v-for="upload in uploads">
  {{ upload.type }}
</div>
```

So `items` should output complete array and `v-for` should filter and output foreach item in that array, which should go the same for `uploads` but problem is `uploads` not working.

This is what i actually get in frontent

For `{{ items }}`

```
[ { "id": 110, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "5.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "3f49191095d302fb7e66ce037dd5efa111287e8230964ad8a3170687ca4336a1", "size": 192445, "created_at": "2019-04-23 16:04:01", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 16:04:01" }, { "id": 111, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "4.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b", "size": 193223, "created_at": "2019-04-23 21:58:52", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 21:58:52" }, { "id": 112, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "5.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b", "size": 192445, "created_at": "2019-04-23 21:58:52", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 21:58:52" }, { "id": 113, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "4.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "ffe6f95d10c5249390fcea140fe15a1fb57f5d29626a947e4a999db50f3ea295", "size": 193223, "created_at": "2019-04-23 22:00:10", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 22:00:10" }, { "id": 114, "user_id": 28, "type": "profilephoto", "name": "4.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg", "extension": "jpg", "path": "75a00a901f1a01a0267d44bebc8574efa9eb7a7edfd395e29dabb289efb353ac", "size": 193223, "created_at": "2019-04-23 22:05:32", "updated_at": "2019-04-23 22:05:32" } ]
```

And there `v-for="item in items"` logic works, if i do

```
<li v-for="item in items">
   {{ item.type }}
</li>
```

I will get list of `item.type`

The problem happens if i do exactly the same with `uploads` something is not working.

If i test output of `{{ uploads }}` i will get exactly same array as with items except there are spaces between things in array.

This is output of `{{ uploads }}`

```
[{"id":110,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"5.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"3f49191095d302fb7e66ce037dd5efa111287e8230964ad8a3170687ca4336a1","size":192445,"created_at":"2019-04-23 16:04:01","updated_at":"2019-04-23 16:04:01"},{"id":111,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52","updated_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52"},{"id":112,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"5.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"0bd693c2cd1ab5ec2c7223fc6a92356ab68c52e8cc0b7d5d5aa5b4a230cf015b","size":192445,"created_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52","updated_at":"2019-04-23 21:58:52"},{"id":113,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"ffe6f95d10c5249390fcea140fe15a1fb57f5d29626a947e4a999db50f3ea295","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:00:10","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:00:10"},{"id":114,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"75a00a901f1a01a0267d44bebc8574efa9eb7a7edfd395e29dabb289efb353ac","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:05:32","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:05:32"},{"id":115,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"c0db13b85c255a30b8466ca5778cad05d06f20f2cf12a3db46e9b6a7d182fdd8","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:14:37","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:14:37"},{"id":116,"user_id":28,"type":"profilephoto","name":"4.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","extension":"jpg","path":"3591cedc64c8f3638d71643291ce2e37d697dbcdfe08c715254d94237b93b1a1","size":193223,"created_at":"2019-04-23 22:21:37","updated_at":"2019-04-23 22:21:37"}]
```

And if i try to do

```
<div v-for="upload in uploads">
  {{ upload.type }}
</div>
```

I get whole bunch of empty div's without `upload.type` output. Plus i have like 20 images in total, i get like 200 empty div's.

This confuses me alot as why it is happening like this, any suggestions?

Comment: instead of this ```:input_value="'{{ json_encode($profilephotos) }}'"```
put this ```:input_value="{{ json_encode($profilephotos) }}"```

Comment: @Abdurrhman Thanks for clarification, that's exactly what i wanted to find out, difference between using quotations and not using them. I am new to vue js and i just started learning, about underscore so this means best practice would be to use camel case in any prop names.

Answer (score 1):

with »Quotation Singletick« "' you enter the »string« mode - which is not a variable but the chars you enter/ Laravel suplies.

Something from the best practice side: Don't use underscore in attrbutes/variable/prop names. Vue converts ":input-value" (kebab-case) to "inputValue" (camelCase) for you inside the component.

Last but not least. Make sure to always supply a key for your v-for list. Like

```
<li v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index"></li>
```

Hope that helps